# The "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications" package doesn't seem to work in C++ with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, notifications, toast, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to implement the Microsoft UWP notification system in my C++ program, but I am encountering a problem. I followed the procedure on the Microsoft site: [Send a local toast notification from C++ UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-cpp-uwp?tabs=builder-syntax)

But when adding namespaces ;

```
using namespace Microsoft::Toolkit::Uwp::Notifications;
```

the namespace is unfindable, even after added NuGet package "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications".

After adding the NuGet package "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications", when I add the namespaces declaration in my C++ program, I get the error `Error (active) E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace`. It's as if the namespaces couldn't be found.

[image: My program example]

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked my reply about `Error (active) E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace`?

Comment: Hi ! 
Yes I checked, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add `winrt/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.h` in the pch.h file, clean the project and re-build the project, will there be the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio cannot find the namespace, please add the header file in your **pch.h** file.

```
#include <winrt/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.h>
```